# Cannot Transform GeoJSON to TopoJOSN

Tags: javascript, html, topojson, vega-lite

I am **trying to transform GeoJSON to TopoJOSN in order to put into Vega-Lite. Therefore I can draw a map.**

I used https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/ to download the **.json** for **map Oceania (Low resolution)**, then I put this file into https://mapshaper.org/ so that I can export it again as **.topojson**

**However, even I choose export as .topojson**, the file still give me **.json**. **Because when I put this URL to Vega-Late, it cannot display a Oceania map.** (My code at the very bottom of the question)

**Anyone know how can I transform into topojson? Or even maybe there is anything wrong with my URL?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple issues with your specification:

- your GeoJSON file does not include a feature named `"states"`. It includes a feature named `"custom"`.
- you are using the `albersusa` projection, which only shows the USA, and your GeoJSON has no data within this boundary.

Fixing these issues, and using an orthographic [projection](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/projection.html) centered on Australia, gives you a better chart ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgCsABh1L4NMljQBmPUsFIAnnABOaANqg1STClSgGdwWgzY8QgI7JGVqOkYmBgh7KDlMOFlMSjiEAgAhNjjZMgAtGCQ2AA4AJlMCAFlrAH0AMRo7CExqgHU4JhwkMjh+AmQaWQIAQWjkHGo4NikZeSUAMzY7ZEw0UExrHDg-TDYcNmk5RRA5uDdvLfQoaJ2EEABfO6VkOwBrVZB1zb9utggCr-mNEEvnQwmMmDIIWsRyadjYLwuKhgInujxcbg8Xh8fiwuHwRBCYVo9GY0Vi8USyVSGSycjyBWKZUqNXqjWabQ6XR6fSQA2CvNkcyQwOqmHU1hSEGI9yeSFefigDSggi2SkScTUAzI70EdLoDDUF1AcxocEEaj8upy+sNR0+iIAjgwkEk6G4aKQZSArGLMAajcdTebLe6-balPa-E6Xb73Z7HiAIDQAF4B4jChgXACMOgTcV1Dk8IHTgkzfiacDNTFLWwedwAukpsibtUWcHDJHAoGLDkXI+hFvQ2JCkDhkVAjnD3AknPws2J9OYFDp63WgA)):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 300,
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BocongZhao823/My_First_Webpage-/main/Ausmap.geo.json",
        "format": {
          "type": "topojson",
          "feature": "custom"
        }
      },
      "mark": {
        "type": "geoshape",
        "fill": "lightgray",
        "stroke": "white"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BocongZhao823/My_First_Webpage-/main/rainfall_tidy.csv"
      },
      "mark": "circle",
      "encoding": {
        "longitude": {
          "field": "longitude",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "latitude": {
          "field": "latitude",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "size": {"value": 10},
        "color": {"value": "steelblue"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "projection": {
      "type": "orthographic",
      "rotate": [-140, 30, 0]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanations! Where can I find the name of features in GeoJSON file? It's pretty missy when I open the GeoJSON file. (i.e. What key words can I looking for in this file?)

Comment: The features are the keys in the `"objects"` entry.